# Unsupported operand types error / Carriage return - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, char, carriage-return

I am working with Moodle 2.2.1 but have a basic php-mysql problem. I am trying to return a count of a field with a condition in my WHERE clause. The WHERE clause condition is coming from a foreach loop.This is my code:

```
    foreach($allunits as $allunit)
    {
     $countquery = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(uid.userid) FROM {user_info_data} uid WHERE uid.data = '".$allunit."' OR uid.data = '".$allunit."\r'");
     $ucount = $ucount + $countquery;       
    }
```

This throws an unsupported operand types error. Since the 'data' field can have junk lines/spaces added to it I need to use \r to search for such values. If i directly pass the value in wHERE clause it works fine, like this,

```
    SELECT COUNT(uid.data) FROM {user_info_data} WHERE uid.data = 'Marketing' OR uid.data = 'Marketing\r'
```

but my wHERE clause value needs to come from an array.

Can any one help me out with this problem?

Thanks

EDIT: a var_dump of my array '$allunits'

```
array(118) {
  [0] => string(9) "PBS Group"
  [1] => string(15) "Admin-PBS Group"
  [2] => string(15) "Sales Functions"
  [3] => string(17) "Support Functions"
  [4] => string(10) "Executives"
  [5] => string(4) "Nemo"
  [6] => string(7) "Prop Co"
  [7] => string(21) "Admin-Sales Functions"
  [8] => string(7) "Connect"
  [9] => string(12) "Intermediary"
  [10] => string(6) "Retail"
  [11] => string(13) "Sales Support"
  [12] => string(15) "Business Change"
  [13] => string(13) "Group Finance"
  [14] => string(2) "HR"
  [15] => string(16) "IT and eChannels"
  [16] => string(9) "Marketing"
  [17] => string(15) "Member Services"
  [18] => string(9) "Oversight"
  [19] => string(24) "Executives and Directors"
  [20] => string(19) "Personal Assistants"
  [21] => string(19) "Corporate Property "
  [22] => string(10) "Peter Alan"
  [23] => string(8) "Premises"
  [24] => string(18) "Property Solutions"
  [25] => string(9) "Surveyors"
  [26] => string(13) "Connect Sales"
  [27] => string(15) "Connect Service"
  [28] => string(12) "Retail Sales"
  [29] => string(15) "Regulated Sales"
  [30] => string(21) "Administration-Retail"
  [31] => string(19) "Business Partnering"
  [32] => string(21) "Capital and Liquidity"
  [33] => string(18) "Finance Operations"
  [34] => string(11) "Procurement"
  [35] => string(15) "Risk Management"
  [36] => string(8) "Treasury"
  [37] => string(8) "Group HR"
  [38] => string(9) "Group LnD"
  [39] => string(9) "eChannels"
  [40] => string(29) "eChannels Sales and Marketing"
  [41] => string(15) "IT Architecture"
  [42] => string(11) "IT Delivery"
  [43] => string(11) "IT Services"
  [44] => string(19) "Business Operations"
  [45] => string(11) "Collections"
  [46] => string(23) "Mortgage Administration"
  [47] => string(3) "MSC"
  [48] => string(8) "Registry"
  [49] => string(7) "Savings"
  [50] => string(22) "Group Business Conduct"
  [51] => string(32) "Group Financial Crime Prevention"
  [52] => string(26) "Group Information Security"
  [53] => string(14) "Group Internal"
  [54] => string(14) "Legal Services"
  [55] => string(11) "Secretariat"
  [56] => string(25) "Administration-Peter Alan"
  [57] => string(7) "Agency "
  [58] => string(8) "Lettings"
  [59] => string(17) "Retail Sales City"
  [60] => string(17) "Retail Sales East"
  [61] => string(18) "Retail Sales North"
  [62] => string(18) "Retail Sales South"
  [63] => string(17) "Retail Sales West"
  [64] => string(21) "Regulated Sales South"
  [65] => string(20) "Regulated Sales West"
  [66] => string(29) "Albany Road-Retail Sales City"
  [67] => string(23) "Barry-Retail Sales City"
  [68] => string(28) "Birchgrove-Retail Sales City"
  [69] => string(24) "Canton-Retail Sales City"
  [70] => string(26) "Llandaff-Retail Sales City"
  [71] => string(25) "Penarth-Retail Sales City"
  [72] => string(27) "Llanishen-Retail Sales City"
  [73] => string(30) "Queen Street-Retail Sales City"
  [74] => string(24) "Rumney-Retail Sales City"
  [75] => string(31) "St Davids two-Retail Sales City"
  [76] => string(28) "Whitchurch-Retail Sales City"
  [77] => string(26) "Aberdare-Retail Sales East"
  [78] => string(29) "Abergavenny-Retail Sales East"
  [79] => string(27) "Blackwood-Retail Sales East"
  [80] => string(28) "Caerphilly-Retail Sales East"
  [81] => string(27) "Ebbw Vale-Retail Sales East"
  [82] => string(26) "Hereford-Retail Sales East"
  [83] => string(35) "Llandrindod Wells-Retail Sales East"
  [84] => string(32) "Merthyr Tydfil-Retail Sales East"
  [85] => string(26) "Monmouth-Retail Sales East"
  [86] => string(25) "Newport-Retail Sales East"
  [87] => string(27) "Pontypool-Retail Sales East"
  [88] => string(25) "Bangor-Retail Sales North"
  [89] => string(26) "Chester-Retail Sales North"
  [90] => string(26) "Denbigh-Retail Sales North"
  [91] => string(28) "Llandudno-Retail Sales North"
  [92] => string(23) "Mold-Retail Sales North"
  [93] => string(28) "Prestatyn-Retail Sales North"
  [94] => string(27) "Pwllheli-Retail Sales North"
  [95] => string(29) "Shrewsbury-Retail Sales North"
  [96] => string(26) "Wrexham-Retail Sales North"
  [97] => string(27) "Bridgend-Retail Sales South"
  [98] => string(28) "Cowbridge-Retail Sales South"
  [99] => string(33) "Llantwit Major-Retail Sales South"
  [100] => string(26) "Maesteg-Retail Sales South"
  [101] => string(24) "Neath-Retail Sales South"
  [102] => string(29) "Pontypridd-Retail Sales South"
  [103] => string(28) "Porthcawl-Retail Sales South"
  [104] => string(30) "Port Talbot-Retail Sales South"
  [105] => string(28) "Tonypandy-Retail Sales South"
  [106] => string(27) "Treorchy-Retail Sales South"
  [107] => string(29) "Aberystwyth-Retail Sales West"
  [108] => string(28) "Carmarthen-Retail Sales West"
  [109] => string(27) "Fishguard-Retail Sales West"
  [110] => string(27) "Gorseinon-Retail Sales West"
  [111] => string(31) "Haverfordwest-Retail Sales West"
  [112] => string(27) "Llampeter-Retail Sales West"
  [113] => string(27) "Llandeilo-Retail Sales West"
  [114] => string(26) "Llanelli-Retail Sales West"
  [115] => string(27) "Morriston-Retail Sales West"
  [116] => string(25) "Mumbles-Retail Sales West"
  [117] => string(25) "Swansea-Retail Sales West"
}
```

Comment: Does the `data` column have _literal_ `\r` in it? If so, you must use a single-quoted string in PHP as in `'\r\''`

Comment: You sure it's just the `WHERE` clause, this `{user_info_data}` seems incomplete.

Comment: I'm sorry. I dint get u. what do u mean if the column has literal '\r'? I don't think it has. I guess the 'data' column can have multiple values for one record but my column will always have one value so mayb thatsy junk spaces/lines getting added.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary In moodle the table name is specified as {user_info_data} instead of tbl_user_info_data or mdl_uer_info_data. And as i said, the query returns the count fine if i directly pas the value (See my question). Its just when the value is coming from an array, teh problem appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a literal carriage return, instead of the string `\r` which is what is required. This is because your string is enclosed in double quotes and PHP is interpreting the escape sequence before it is passed to MySQL.

The solution is simple - either enclose your SQL string in single quotes, or even simpler, escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
$countquery = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(uid.userid) FROM {user_info_data} uid WHERE uid.data = '".$allunit."' OR uid.data = '".$allunit."\\r'");
```

**EDIT**

I think this will do what you want in a single query with no looping:

```
$query = "
  SELECT COUNT(uid.data) AS users
  FROM {user_info_data}
  WHERE uid.data IN ('".implode("','", $allunits)."','".implode("\\r','", $allunits)."\\r')
";
$countquery = $DB->get_records_sql($query);
$ucount = $countquery->users;
```

Comment: I tried both. Tried writing the query in single quotes with my 'data' value in double quotes with '\r'. And also tried writing the way you have written above with another backslash. Dint work. Sorry

Comment: Wait a second, I have just realised what that error is telling you. It's not a problem with the query, it's a problem with the `$ucount = $ucount + $countquery;` line. You are trying to add an array of objects to what is presumably an integer (given that it is called `$ucount`), which makes no semantic sense. What are you actually expecting this code to do? Do you actually want the records returned by the query, or just the number of matching records?

Comment: The error is on line 136 which is the query line. N presumably my query is returning a count which is a number. I am just adding that number to `$ucount` which is declared as `$ucount = 0`, and hence I am just adding it to `$ucount`

Comment: I tried doing a `print_r($DB->get_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(uid.userid) FROM {user_info_data} uid WHERE uid.data = '".$allunit."' OR uid.data = '".$allunit."\\r'")` n that still was throwing an error. So definitely its not recognizing the `\r` in the query which is why the error.

Comment: Do me a favour and try changing the line to `$ucount += (int) $countquery;` and see if you still get the error...

Comment: I got it working with your previous solution of adding double backslashes. Also instead of directly writing `$ucount = $ucount + $countquery` I changed my query to `"SELECT COUNT(uid.userid) AS users FROM {user_info_data} uid WHERE uid.data = '".$allunit."' OR uid.data = '".$allunit."\\r'"` and ran a `foreach` loop, wrote `$ucount = $ucount + $countquery->users`

Comment: I guess the file wasn't getting saved or something which is why it did not reflect your change of \\r. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Cool - but I can;t help thinking there is a more efficient, single query way to do this - see edit above in 1 minute.